# JQuery OnHover working unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Goal**: Highlight a table row that's apart of tbody on Hover.

**Problem**: Hover gets 'buggy' when an other than a simple input[type=text] is in the td that the mouse enters. Ex. When my mouse crosses into the tr at the location of a td that contains a input[type=datetime-local] the mouseenter event does not fire. Same goes for input[type=date], select, input[type=checkbox], etc.

**Code**:

```
<table class="myClass">
    <thead data-bind="template: { name: 'SummaryTableHeaderTemplate'}">
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'SummaryTableBodyTemplate', foreach: $data }">
    </tbody>
</table>

function OnHoverIn() {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
}
function OnHoverOut() {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
}
$("table.myClass").on("mouseenter", "tr", OnHoverIn);
$("table.myClass").on("mouseleave", "tr", OnHoverOut);
$("table.myClass").on("mouseover", "tr", OnHoverIn);
```

**What I've tried**:
I've tried many variations of this, `$("tbody tr").hover(....my two functions above...);` and I've tried without the `"mouseover"` event as well. They all behave the same.

**Question**: How do I get onHoverIn/Out to activate regardless of what is in the tr/td?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Working on it, oddly enough my exact code isn't working in the jsfiddle haha? I think I added the jQuery wrong, but code-wise I think it's all there. http://jsfiddle.net/9esmZ/14/

Comment: Technically everyone answered my question correctly as I wasn't entirely accurate as to what the problem was, but Laurent's answer led me to my problem, so I marked it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tr").hover(
        function() { // Hover in
            $(this).addClass("hoverClass");
        }, function() { // Hover out
            $(this).removeClass("hoverClass");
        }
    );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9esmZ/27/

Comment: Hmm...this does shed a little bit of light on my problem. It's odd really. I added more than just one row to the table and it works perfectly. I have no idea why it would act that way, even if I keep the problem spot as the bottom row it doesn't do it anymore once I add more rows 0.o

Comment: @Shelby115 your problem was the first row? according to your question, it should not be highlighted, since you said rows that are part of body should be highlighted.. the first row is a part of head.. so either the question is wrong or the answer is wrong :)

Comment: What you are doing is binding the `hover` function to all `tr` elements. When new elements are added after this `.hover` function has been declared, this won't work. In a such case you will need to use an `.on` function.

Comment: @TilwinJoy First row of the Tbody, not the actual first row (aka header). The first row highlighted just not while entering the bottom of the single td that had the input[type=datetime-local]. It works if there are multiple rows so it really doesn't matter as in production there will never only be one row.

Answer (score 1):

check this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/9esmZ/26/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function OnHoverIn() {
    $(this).children().addClass("hover");
};
function OnHoverOut() {
    $(this).children().removeClass("hover");
};  

$(document).on("mouseenter", "tbody tr", OnHoverIn);
$(document).on("mouseleave", "tbody tr", OnHoverOut);
});
```